# Entering Developer Menu in Google's M1 android emulator

Tags: debugging, android-emulator, react-native

I'm using the preview of Google's Android emulator on my M1 mac and I need to debug a React Native app but every debugging method I can find needs access to the developer menu and I cannot get that to come up.  I've tried simulating shaking, command m, adb shell input keyevent 82 none of those bring up the developer menu.